# PHP exif_read_data returns wrong and incomplete data

Tags: php, exif

I’m trying to read some exif data from my images using exif_read_data. However, it seems like the returned data is partially wrong or incomplete.

You can have a look at [this image](http://fotos.danielrauber.de/images/DSC01386.jpg), which obviously contains a lot of exif data, as seen [in this exif reader](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffotos.danielrauber.de%2Fimages%2FDSC01386.jpg).

Trying to read the camera model (exif key "Model") however returns some part of my name and camera manufacturer (exif key "Make") is not even showing up.

I logged all information by using `print_r(exif_read_data($imageUrl, 'EXIF, IFD0'));` and the result is the following:

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => DSC01386.jpg
    [FileDateTime] => 1433003804
    [FileSize] => 465667
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF, GPS
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="1367" height="2048"
            [Height] => 2048
            [Width] => 1367
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/2.8
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
        )

    [Make] => Danie
    [Model] =>  Rauber
    [Orientation] => 1
    [UndefinedTag:0x0001] =>  
    [YResolution] => 35417705/1108475996
    [ResolutionUnit] => 2
    [Software] => ezirk Lichtenberg_
    [DateTime] => utschlandt
    [Artist] =>  Rauber
    [Copyright] => 
    [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 266
    [GPS_IFD_Pointer] => 868
    [THUMBNAIL] => Array
        (
            [Compression] => 6
            [XResolution] => 72/1
            [YResolution] => 72/1
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 1096
            [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 12738
        )

    [ExposureTime] => 1/3200
    [FNumber] => 28/10
    [ExposureProgram] => 3
    [ISOSpeedRatings] => 250
    [UndefinedTag:0x8830] => 2
    [UndefinedTag:0x8832] => 250
    [ExifVersion] => 0230
    [DateTimeOriginal] => 2015:05:29 12:35:09
    [DateTimeDigitized] => 2015:05:29 12:35:09
    [ShutterSpeedValue] => 11643856/1000000
    [ApertureValue] => 2970854/1000000
    [BrightnessValue] => 24144/2560
    [ExposureBiasValue] => 0/10
    [MaxApertureValue] => 760/256
    [MeteringMode] => 5
    [LightSource] => 0
    [Flash] => 16
    [FocalLength] => 350/10
    [ColorSpace] => 1
    [FocalPlaneXResolution] => 67143837/32768
    [FocalPlaneYResolution] => 67143837/32768
    [FocalPlaneResolutionUnit] => 3
    [FileSource] => 
    [SceneType] => 
    [CustomRendered] => 0
    [ExposureMode] => 0
    [WhiteBalance] => 0
    [DigitalZoomRatio] => 16/16
    [FocalLengthIn35mmFilm] => 35
    [SceneCaptureType] => 0
    [Contrast] => 0
    [Saturation] => 0
    [Sharpness] => 0
    [UndefinedTag:0xA432] => Array
        (
            [0] => 350/10
            [1] => 350/10
            [2] => 28/10
            [3] => 28/10
        )

    [UndefinedTag:0xA434] => FE 35mm F2.8 ZA
    [GPSVersion] => ��
    [GPSLatitudeRef] => N
    [GPSLatitude] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52/1
            [1] => 32509/1000
            [2] => 0/1
        )

    [GPSLongitudeRef] => E
    [GPSLongitude] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13/1
            [1] => 300722/10000
            [2] => 0/1
        )

    [GPSAltitude] => 589734/10000
)
```

As you can see, "Model" and "Make" are available, but they contain wrong information. (Same goes for keys like "Software")

Comment: Could the reason be that the camera uses exif 2.3 and PHP can only handle exif 2.2? I’m using PHP 5.4.38

Comment: Hey! Did you solve this problem? Having a similar issue with the model that's correctly shown in Photoshop, but as I read the exif data it's just empty.

Comment: @Manuel I didn’t yet find a solution for this problem with PHP. However, other libraries (e.g. for node.js) don’t have this issue.